# I am writing script in batch command and I am trying to replace a variable inside a loop

Tags: batch, adb

script 1

```
echo off
set /a flag = 0
set /a flag = 1
pause
```

script 2

```
echo off
set /a flag = 0
for /l %%x in (1,1,3) do (
    if %flag% == 0 (set /a flag = 1)
    echo %flag%
)
pause
```

script 1 is working and the output is the number 1.

script 2 is not working and the output is always 0.

Answer (score 1):

The legendary @DavidPostill said `You need to use delayed expansion when using variable inside a loop.` .. ***NOT TRUE!***.  This is perhaps the easiest method to explian but that is but one solution to this problem.  We were solving this problem LONG BEFORE `enabledelayedexpansion` even existed using `call :label_name <params>` and `goto :EOF` syntax.  I still prefer this syntax as it seems to be more like `gosub` and `return` back in the days of basic than this abomination of changing `%` to `!`.

### script 2

```
:: Think of this part as main().  It quits and exits at the goto :EOF
echo off
set /a flag = 0
for /l %%x in (1,1,3) do call :show_flag "%%x"
pause
goto :EOF

:: -----------------------------------------------------------------------
:: Our function here is not bound by the rules mentioned in other answers.
:: we can change the values of variables in here and they will be handled
:: properly.
:: -----------------------------------------------------------------------
:: function show_flag
:: -----------------------------------------------------------------------
:show_flag
    set incoming_flag_param=%~0
    if [%incoming_flag_param%] == [0] (set /a flag = 1)
    echo %flag%
    goto :EOF
```

If you wonder how long has this syntax existed?  I believe that I used it against the ORIGINAL cmd.exe / NT3.51.

Answer (score 0):

#### Script 2 is not working and the output is always 0.

You need to use delayed expansion when using variable inside a loop.

> **Delayed Expansion will cause variables within a batch file to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time, this option is turned on with the `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` command.**
>
> - Variable expansion means replacing a variable (e.g. %windir%) with
>   its value C:\WINDOWS
> - **By default expansion will happen just once, before each line is executed.**
> - In this case, a "line" includes bracketed expressions even if they are formatted to run over several lines.
> - When !delayed! expansion is turned on, the variables will be expanded each time the line is executed, or for each loop in a `FOR`
>   looping command.
> - With loop commands like `FOR`, compound or bracketed expressions,
>   **Delayed Expansion will allow you to always read the current value of
>   the variable.** You can write new variable values with or without
>   Delayed Expansion.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Source: [EnableDelayedExpansion - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

You will then need to replace `%flag%` with `!flag!`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a flag = 0
for /l %%x in (1,1,3) do (
    if %flag% == 0 (set /a flag = 1)
    echo !flag!
)
pause
endlocal
```

Output:

```
1
1
1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Potentially more useful:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a flag = 0
for /l %%x in (1,1,3) do (
    if %flag% == 0 (set /a flag = %%x)
    echo !flag!
)
pause
endlocal
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)